# Conditinal style class in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

There is default style class,
Need to override its elements with another class, check the image below.

How can I achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should destructure after condition, not before condition.

```
<div style={{
    ...local,
    ...(src ? customLogo: {})
}}>
```